# simple for order ODE simulation with Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I am experimenting with the simulation capability of `pyomo` and have this simple script to simulate a first order ODE:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.clf()
# Define a model
m = ConcreteModel()

# Define time and discretize it
m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0, 1))
m.tau = TransformationFactory('dae.finite_difference')
m.tau.apply_to(m, nfe=500, scheme='BACKWARD')

# Define variables
m.x = Var(m.t)
m.dxdt = DerivativeVar(m.x)

# Initial condition
m.ic = Constraint(expr=m.x[0] == 1)
m.x[0].fix(1)  # or any other non-zero value

# DAE Equation (a simple differential equation: dx/dt + 10*x = 0)
#time constant should be 100ms
m.ode = Constraint(m.t, rule=lambda m, t: m.dxdt[t] + 10*m.x[t] == 0)

# Solve the model
solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
results = solver.solve(m, tee=True)

# Extract the results and plot
time_points = [t for t in m.t]
x_values = [m.x[t]() for t in m.t]
%matplotlib ipympl
plt.plot(time_points, x_values, label='x(t)')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Time Evolution of x(t)')
plt.show()
```

Which outputs a plot like
[image: 1st order response]
However, this clearly isn't an exponential decay as I'd expect. The time constant should be 100ms. I've changed the `nfe` parameter a couple times. It just seems like the output has the first sample at the initial condition, and then the second sample goes to zero, and stays there. Why doesn't it show the predictable exponential decay?

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.clf()
# Define a model
m = ConcreteModel()

# Define time and discretize it
m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0, 1))

# Define variables
m.x = Var(m.t)
m.dxdt = DerivativeVar(m.x)

# Initial condition
m.x[0].fix(1)  # or any other non-zero value

# DAE Equation (a simple differential equation: dx/dt + 10*x = 0)
#time constant should be 100ms
m.ode = Constraint(m.t, rule=lambda m, t: m.dxdt[t] + 10*m.x[t] == 0)

def simulate_model(m):
    sim = Simulator(m, package='scipy')
    tsim, profiles = sim.simulate(numpoints=100, integrator='vode')

    # Discretize model using Orthogonal Collocation
    m.tau = TransformationFactory('dae.finite_difference')
    m.tau.apply_to(m, nfe=500, scheme='BACKWARD')   

    # Initialize the discretized model using the simulator profiles
    sim.initialize_model()

    return sim, tsim, profiles

sim, tsim, profiles = simulate_model(m)

# Extract the results and plot
time_points = [t for t in m.t]
x_values = [m.x[t]() for t in m.t]
%matplotlib ipympl
plt.plot(time_points, x_values, label='x(t)')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Time Evolution of x(t)')
plt.show()
```

[image]
I found the [DAE example directory](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/main/examples/dae) and realized I wasn't actually simulating before, but solving.